# Flutter navigation animations

Tags: dart, flutter

We are wanting to design a flutter application that navigates the way that the app "Reflectly" does. It looks very similar to responsive web sites with a parallax type design. I'm including screen shots in case you haven't seen it.

I have begun replacing the MaterialPageRoute with CupertinoPageRoutes and it basically has changed the navigation to a sliding effect from right to left.

If you look at the navigation arrows they are on the bottom right hand side vertically.

Im not sure how to be sure but is it possible this is just one page?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try to wrap your view in a `PageView` with `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`.

You can also customize the way you want to handle multiple events and so by providing a custom `PageController`.

From what I’ve seen in that app (downloaded to get an idea) it seems to be suitable for what you’re looking for.